# Microsoft Charts and AJAX

Tags: c#, .net, charts

The data that's required for the charts to be drawn comes from an AJAX call (PageMethod call) and the chart needs to be re/drawn after the PageMethod call is completed. Is it possible to redraw the MS chart from JS without using the UpdatePanel??

Comment: What's your problem with using an update panel?

Comment: <Quote> What's your problem with using an update panel?
The evils of it
What kind of chart is this? - A Pie chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used ICallbackEventHandler